# What is the difference between Amazon On demand & On demand Capacity reservation EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

AWS Documents says

**On-Demand Capacity Reservations** enable you to reserve compute capacity for your Amazon EC2 instances in a specific Availability Zone for any duration

**With On-Demand Instances**, you pay for compute capacity by the second with no long-term commitments.

***So what is the difference between these two ?***

Answer (score 3):

A 'Capacity Reservation' resource allocates the relevant compute capacity you choose, based on that resource you can launch an EC2 instance. You may terminate the instance, but still own that capacity for any other EC2 instance. You're paying for the 'Capacity Reservation' from the moment you've created it.

In contrast to EC2 instance, once you create and terminate it, no guarantee you'll have the capacity to create another one afterward.

Comment: What do you mean by "no guarantee you'll have the capacity to create another one afterward"? Does this mean that AWS may not be able to give you another instance if other clients have higher demands? Or does it mean that you might not have the funds to get one?

Comment: @heretoinfinity, the first one. Once you release the host of your EC2 instance, it's available for use for any AWS client.